# CGI application throws “System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission”

Tags: .net, iis-6, permissions, cgi

I'm working on a simple .NET application which is supposed to run under IIS6 through CGI. First of all everything works great on my Windows 7 development machine under IIS 7.5. But I'm stuck with “System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission” under IIS6.

I've already tried to sign the assembly by the way. But I guess the issue is in another direction, because the application is launched well from console. So I think application pool user doesn't have needed permissions.
Would you please point me where I should check the permissions.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing through the Internet and found the solution. Please see it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/rahulso/archive/2006/11/29/how-to-run-a-simple-c-cgi-exe-from-command-prompt.aspx

If you don't have management console for .NET 2.0 you should install .NET SDK.